# Finding sample size given confidence interval for an unknown distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, estimation, confidence-interval

Is it possible to find sample size given confidence interval for an unknown distribution? If so, what parameters of the distribution are needed?

This came from the problem:
There is a population of size 10^12, each individual has a value of either 0 or 1, we don't know what the distribution of the population is, and we want to estimate the percentage of 0 and 1 of the population. What should we do? How many samples do we need?

Edit: each individual does NOT take 0/1 with the same probability, so it's not Bernoulli distribution.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the original problem. Each individual having value 0 or 1 sounds like Bernoulli. What do you mean by not knowing the distribution of the population?

Comment: Only the confidence interval will not be enough, you need some other info

Comment: @JirapatSamranvedhya   it's not Bernoulli, each individual does not takes 0 or 1 with the same probability. All we know is they are 0/1 values and want to know the percentage of 0 and 1.

Comment: @kjetil Do you know what other info we should find out in order to find the sample size?

Comment: Since *"each individual has a value of either $0$ or $1$"* and there is a finite population, this is not a Bernoulli distribution.  But the population of $10^{12}$ is huge, so any random sample of size $n$ without replacement where $n \ll 10^{12}$ will behave almost as if it has a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$, where $p$ is the proportion of the population with value $1$.  For an infinite population the standard error of the mean is $\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}$ while for the finite population sampled without replacement it is $\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}\times \frac{N-n}{N}}$